# how to dynamically change column chart to mirror chart using highchart

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, charts, highcharts

Well, today I come across to highchart issue where I am trying to fix something like following:
1. I am making call to ajax and then changing column chart series data like this:

```
if(data == 2) {

chart.series[0].setData([
['2009', 140],['2010', 200],['2011',   100],
['2009', -200],['2010',   -120],['2011', -240]]);
}
```

2. What I want is to display this information into mirror chart way with two group names "UK", "AUS" so data will display like this UK - 2009, 2010, 2011 and same with AUS 2009, 2010, 2011(but with negative values)
3. for what I want demo is here http://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-negative

So, in short if ajax bring data = 2 from php page then I wanted convert column chart values into negative chart values with group series like attach highcahrt demo link.

Guys I am trying to resolve this for so long now and really need help. So it will be great if someone know how I can do with chart.series[0].setData or any other method out there. Thanks in advanced

Hi I want my graph like this dynamically 
[image]

and I am getting answer like this at the moment after suggest answer:
[image]

Code:

```
                                function requestData() {
                                    chart = $('#column_chart').highcharts();

                                    $.ajax({
                                        type: "POST",
                                        url: "graph_advanced_file.php",
                                        data: {sliceName: ch},
                                        success: function(data) {
                                            //store local storage.....

                                            localStorage.setItem("current_item", ch);

                                            //alert(data);
                                            //Now, check whatever data is coming through serve accordingly......to load some data.....of that perticular....
                                            if(data == 1) {
                                                //Travel..so get series data....
                                                <?php
                                                    //$each_slice_series = array();
                                                    //$each_slice_series = getSliceInfo(1);
                                                    //$sliceId = 1;
                                                    //call and get the figure....
                                                ?>
                                                chart.series[0].setData([
                                                ['Mand',   200],
                                                ['Sand',   800],
                                                ['Land', 700]]);
                                            }
                                            if(data == 2) {
                                                //Garment....So get series data....
                                                var options = {
                                                  chart: {
                                                      type: 'column'
                                                  }, 
                                                  plotOptions: {
                                                      series: {
                                                          stacking: 'normal'
                                                      }
                                                  }
                                                };

                                               //Load new options to chart   
                                               chart.setOptions(options);
                                                chart.series[0].setData([
                                                  ['2009', 140],['2010', 200],['2011',   100],
                                                  ['2009', -200],['2010',   -120],['2011', -240]]);

                                               chart.series[0].name="Uk";

                                               chart.series[1].setData([
                                                      ['2009', 180],['2010', 100],['2011',   150],
                                                      ['2009', -250],['2010',   -130],['2011', -270]]);

                                               chart.addSeries({ 
                                                  name: "AUS", 
                                                  data: [ ['2009', 180],
                                                          ['2010', 100],
                                                          ['2011', 150], 
                                                          ['2009', -250],
                                                          ['2010', -130],
                                                          ['2011', -270]] 
                                               });

                                               chart.redraw();

                                                //chart.series[0].setData([
                                                //['2009', 140],['2010', 200],['2011',   100],['2012', 130],['2013', 190],['2014', 220],['2015', 230],
                                                //['2009', -200],['2010',   -120],['2011', -240],['2012', -220],['2013', -150],['2014', -100],['2015', -250],
                                                //]);

                                            }
```

Now, this requestData called by:

```
$('#column_chart').highcharts({
                                     chart: {
                                            type: 'column',
                                            events: {
                                                load: requestData
                                                //click: changeLables
                                            }
                                        },
                                        title: {
                                            text: 'Total Sale of each products'
                                        },
                                        subtitle: {
                                            text: '(Click on product name to display monthly details)'
                                        },
                                        credits: {
                                            enabled: false
                                        },
                                        xAxis: {
                                            type: 'category'
                                        },
                                        yAxis: {
                                            title: {
                                                text: 'Products Sale'
                                            }
                                        },

                                        legend: {
                                            enabled: false
                                        },
                                        series: [{
                                            name: 'Product Sale',
                                            colorByPoint: true,
                                            data: [{
                                                name: 'Mand',
                                                y: 200<?php //echo $each_slice_series[0];?>
                                            }, {
                                                name: 'Land',
                                                y: 800<?php //echo $each_slice_series[1];?>
                                            }, {
                                                name: 'Sand',
                                                y: 700<?php //echo $each_slice_series[2];?>
                                            }]
                                        }]
                                    });//End of chart......
```

Let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to dynamically change column chart to mirror chart you have to do this.

```
if(data == 2) {

   //Create options      
   var options = {
      chart: {
          renderTo: 'container',
          type: 'bar'
      }
    };

   //Load new options to chart   
   chart.setOptions(options);

   //Load new series
   chart.series[0].setData([
      ['2009', 140],['2010', 200],['2011',   100],
      ['2009', -200],['2010',   -120],['2011', -240]]);
   }
}
```

**Edit**

If you have two data and also want to group series by name you have to do this.

```
if(data == 2) {



$('#column_chart').highcharts({ 
   chart: { 
     type: 'column' 
   },   
   plotOptions: { 
     series: { 
       stacking: 'normal' 
     } 
   }, 
   series: [{ 
     name: 'UK', 
     data: [ 
           ['2009', 140],['2010', 200],['2011', 100], 
           ['2009', -200],['2010', -120],['2011', -240]] 
     }, { 
     name: 'AUS', 
     data: [['2009', 180], 
           ['2010', 100], 
           ['2011', 150], 
           ['2009', -250], 
           ['2010', -130], 
           ['2011', -270]] 
           } ] 
    });
}
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: No bro, it didn't as what I want is set to name as well like uk aus  and pretty much same like the link in my question.

Comment: Check now my edited answer. I think it is like you want. Obviously Aus data is not real, is only for the example.

Comment: Hi Bro, it gives me error TypeError: chart.series[1] is undefined

Comment: Ok, this happens because `series[1]` it is not initialized. You have to create it. Cheek now my answer.

Comment: Hi bro, I think we both are really closed to answer but how I get output like above attach screenshot and I still got that error.

Comment: Ok. Now that I have seen this example It is more clear. On options to make an appearance like the example you have to change the chart type to `column` and add `stacking: 'normal'`. Look the example.

Comment: Bro, still stuck oh no....TypeError: chart.setOptions is not a function graph_advanced.php:1030:15
TypeError: chart.setOptions is not a function

Comment: Check my Jsfiddle example. Perhaps It helps more than I. http://jsfiddle.net/wSD7s/62/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84645/discussion-between-sapikelio-and-user2268488).

Comment: Hi Bro, thanks for fiddle but look at this issue when I use chart.setOptions(options) I receive error and also code above this sentence it seems not working here. TypeError: chart.setOptions is not a function

Comment: Hi Bro, well not find the perfect answer but still I am accept your answer as an ans because you helped me a lot to get even close to answer.